# Problems running Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.11 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using wine 5.0.1

Tags: adobe, wine, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to use Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.11 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using wine 5.0.1. However when I try to open it I get the following error:

*The entry point method could not be loaded due to Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.*

I have installed wine 5.0.1 using the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

I also checked that everything was correct using the following commands:

```
wine --version
wine notepad
```

So it was not a problem of wine. Furthermore I installed Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.11 in *~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/* where the file with the .exe extension is in *~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Adobe Digital Editions 4.5* and its name is *DigitalEditions.exe*. Therefore I am using the following commands to run Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.11:

```
cd ~
cd ".wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Adobe Digital Editions 4.5"
wine DigitalEditions.exe
```

I really don't understand the error *The entry point method could not be loaded due to Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.*

I also searched in *Wine Application Database (AppDB)*, specifically in https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33276 but I didn't find any help, only a screenshot of someone how apparently ran the application.

I am really new to wine. Do I need to install something additional besides wine?

Answer (score 0):

From https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=33733  seems to work for me

Post by spoon0042 » Sun Apr 19, 2020 2:44 pm
Going by the [appdb](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33276) page you will need 'winetricks corefonts dotnet40'. Info on winetricks is here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks

Comment: Please post your answer here and remove the link